# installing a project by shell commands

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, cygwin

I need  shell command to run a project. I use win8 enviroment and i'm not familiar with Linux. I installed Cygwin for this purpose. (I installed default installation without any extra package!)

installation part of ReadME file for this project is:

```
HOW TO INSTALL
> tar  xzvf  DepOE-beta.tar.gz
> sh install-DepOE.sh

Two NLP tools are installed: 
- DepPattern (dependency-based parser)
- Tree-Tagger (PoS tagger)

Pay attention: do not install the package in a directory whose name contain blank spaces!

HOW TO USE
depOE.sh  <tagger> <lang> <file> [parser]

      tagger=freeling, treetagger
      language=gl, es, en, pt, fr
      file=path of the input file
```

the main file is located in  D:\DepOE-beta.tar but every time I use `> tar  xzvf  DepOE-beta.tar.gz` this error is occurred:

[image]

Comment: just so you might get help faster , i think these kind of questions are for superuser forums rather than stakcoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd /cygdrive/d
tar xzvf DepOE-beta.tar.gz
```

cygwin exposes your windows drives under the /cygdrive directory. Note that you must use forward slashes "/" not backslashes to navigate directories in cygwin (as in linux/unix).